# How to solve this trigonometric system of equations?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How to solve this trigonometric system of equations?
\begin{cases}
\sin(x+y)-\sin(x-y)=-\frac{1}{2} \\
\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}

Comment: You should show some effort on the problem, we aren't a howework factory.

Comment: @serena_c Here's a hint: Add the two equations to find $\sin(x+y)$, and then subtract one from another to find $\sin(x-y)$. Now use the angle addition and subtraction formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sin(x+y)=-\frac12,\\\sin(x-y)=0.$$

Comment: IMHO, the hint is incomplete. Given the student is already studying trig eqns, he/she should be at least familiar with this elimination method for solving 2 linear eqns. You should at least mention what the student should do next (use half angle formulas, bla bla)

Comment: @GaurangTandon: a hint is not intended to give the complete solution. This one reduces the problem difficulty to a low level (if need be).

Comment: Ok, fine, I just gave a suggestion.